# Getting a new user's Twitter email address with Django and django-allauth

Tags: python, django, twitter, django-allauth

I'm using the latest version of `django-allauth` and Django 1.8.

I have a custom user model which requires an email address.

When somebody creates a new user by connecting their Twitter account, they are (after a successful OAuth connection) asked for their email address by allauth.

Allauth has no issue with Facebook or Google.

I briefly explored adding email prefill to my custom adapter (a few small changes to `DefaultSocialAccountAdapter`), but the user's email address isn't even in `extra_data`.

Does Twitter purposely not allow you to get a user's email address? It really breaks the flow of my application, as it requires the user to confirm their email address, which is half the point of using social logins in the first place!

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think before you doing with django-allauth you may need to look at this [verify_credentials](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/account/verify_credentials).

And also you have to fill the form and get the approval from Twitter.